# required year, month and day calendar for angular6

Tags: angular6

Error please let me know is there any calendar that works for angular6 having year, month and day tabs. similar to https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-calendar-year-view

Comment: Maybe this one here? [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview)

Comment: I need a calendar with year, month and day view

Comment: You can set this by "displayMonths", maybe you should check the [documentation first](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api)

Comment: any option to get the individual year calendar with next and previous year control

Answer (score 0):

You can try Prime NG calendar in Angular.

It has a lot of options ,to modify it accordingly.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar